# Jquery ajax with PHP filter_input function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

I tried to catch HTML form data with PHP, which are sent from jquery ajax. I'm use jquery `serializeArray()` and `$.post` method to send data. After that I tried to catch my data with php. But my php code is not get that data. Why is that? What are the errors? here my code

## html file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
        <script src="js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input type='text' name='name' />
           <input type='button' id='btn' value='but'/>


        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

## js file

```
$("document").ready(function(){

$('#btn').click(function(){
    var a = $('form').serializeArray();
    $.post('catch.php',{a:a});
});

});
```

## php file

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];

echo filter_input(INPUT_POST, $a[0]['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);



?>
```

** I've used firebug for inspecting output

Comment: does not try it anyone? :(

Comment: Add some debugging code to the PHP to show what it is actually receiving. If you're trying to filter something that isn't present, or is in the wrong format, then you're going to run into problems. Create some logging functions in PHP which you can use to log the result of `var_export($_POST,true)` then go from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation I think it could be simpler to use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

```
<?php
  $a = $_POST['a'];

  foreach ($a as $key => $value){
    echo filter_var($a[$key]['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  }

?>
```

Comment: This supposedly isn't as secure as `filter_input`. I really would like to know why the php team made the `filter_input` function ignore the data posted through ajax. This has been driving me nuts for 10 straight hours. And why isn't this bugging anyone? Does everyone just accept the ajax-posted data and builds them into their sql-queries?